# Arraylist pulled from other class outputting as null despite working correctly in original class

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist, discord-jda

I'm making a rudimentary Discord bot with a profanity filter, and want to use a text file to store the list of words - however despite being read from the text file and being wrote correctly to an array, when trying to pull this array into another class it outputs as null. The scanner class, when run seperately, outputs the data from the arraylist just fine. I've been trying to figure this out for days, I know there's probably a simple solution but I can't get my head around it.

This is my code, I've tried multiple different ways including attributes and constructors but nothing seems to work.

**Scanner class:**

```
Public class ProfanityFile {

    static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String [] args) {
                                
        try(Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("profanityList.txt"))) {
            
            while (s.hasNext()) {
                list.add(s.next());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    
        System.out.println(list); // Outputs correctly
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> getList(ArrayList<String> list) {
        list.addAll(0, ProfanityFile.list);
        System.out.println(ProfanityFile.list + "Profanity File output");
        System.out.println(list + "Event Listener Output");
        return list;
    }
}
```

**Listener class (where I want to use the arraylist data):**

```
public class EventListener extends ListenerAdapter {
    
    static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
                
        EventListener.list = ProfanityFile.getList(EventListener.list);
        System.out.println(EventListener.list);

        String message = event.getMessage().getContentRaw();
        
        for(int i = 0;i < list.size(); i++) {

            if (message.contains(list.get(i))) {
                event.getMessage().delete().queue();
                event.getChannel().sendMessage("Don't say that!").queue();
                return;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main method of the class is not run when you don't directly execute that file.

Instead, you could use a static block.

```java
static List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
static {
    // move code that loads the file and populates the list from main to here
}
```

You could also make a method that returns the `List` from reading the file, and initialize `list` using it.

```java
private static final List<String> list = getWords();
private static List<String> getWords() {
    try {
        return Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("profanityList.txt"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e); 
        // or handle the Exception in some other manner
    }
}
```